# TraceSource - set autoflush to true without config file?

Tags: c#, .net

I don't see autoflush option on TraceSource like there is for Trace.
Is there a way to autoflush without having to flush manually after each write?

BTW I'm using TextWriterTraceListener as my trace source listener and not using config xml.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Internally `TraceSource` uses `AutoFlush` setting of `Trace` class. E.g. [sources](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/diagnostics/TraceSource.cs#75c4627b6b279433) of `TraceSource.TraceEvent` method:

```
for (int j = 0; j < this.listeners.Count; j++)
{
    TraceListener listener = this.listeners[j];
    listener.TraceEvent(eventCache, this.Name, eventType, id, format, args);
    if (Trace.AutoFlush)
    {
        listener.Flush();
    }
}
```

So, all you need to do, is set `Trace.AutoFlush` to true. BTW same is stated in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.diagnostics.tracesource):

> The trace listeners use the values of the Trace class properties
>   Indent, IndentSize, and AutoFlush to format trace output.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this!

```
TextWriterTraceListener listener = new TextWriterTraceListener(@"C:\MyFolder\Temp.log");
StreamWriter sw = listener.Writer as StreamWriter;
if (sw != null) sw.AutoFlush = true;
```

Comment: When you are copy-pasting something from [other site](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/325e84cd-e2da-4c4e-8304-818a176e2a39/how-to-flush-tracesource-authomatically) its good to add link and some explanations

Answer (score 0):

```
StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(path);

traceSource.Listeners.Add(new TextWriterTraceListener(sw) { TraceOutputOptions = TraceOptions.DateTime });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. To make it more useful, it's a good idea to include some explanation that covers why your code solves the OP's original issue, and maybe even why it's a better solution than the answers already posted.